# Iterating through date ranges and sum the values

Tags: python, pandas

For stackoverflow purposes Ill make up some data which is 2 years of time series per day for `value1` & `value2`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(11)

rows,cols = 730,2
data = np.random.rand(rows,cols) 
tidx = pd.date_range('2017-11-15', periods=rows, freq='D') 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['value1','value2'], index=tidx)
```

This nested dictionary below is something that I fat fingered together and I am attempting to sum value 1 & 2 between these date ranges. My real world example (utility bills) just happens to be starting on the 15th and ending on the 14th of each month, but this is almost always different for account to account. The nested dictionary name equals the second date listed in the nested dictionary. (hopefully that makes sense)

```
dates = {
    'dec17' : {'11-15-2017' : '12-14-2017'},
    'jan18' : {'12-15-2017' : '01-14-2018'},
    'feb18' : {'01-15-2018' : '02-14-2018'},
    'mar18' : {'02-15-2018' : '03-14-2018'},
    'apr18' : {'03-15-2018' : '04-14-2018'},
    'may18' : {'04-15-2018' : '05-14-2018'},
    'jun18' : {'05-15-2018' : '06-14-2017'},
    'jul18' : {'06-15-2018' : '07-14-2018'},
    'aug18' : {'07-15-2018' : '08-14-2018'},
    'sep18' : {'08-15-2018' : '09-14-2018'},
    'oct18' : {'09-15-2018' : '10-14-2018'},
    'nov18' : {'10-15-2018' : '11-14-2018'},
    'dec18' : {'11-15-2018' : '12-14-2018'},
    'jan19' : {'12-15-2018' : '01-14-2019'},
    'feb19' : {'01-15-2019' : '02-14-2019'},
    'mar19' : {'02-15-2019' : '03-14-2019'},
    'apr19' : {'03-15-2019' : '04-14-2019'},
    'may19' : {'04-15-2019' : '05-14-2019'},
    'jun19' : {'05-15-2019' : '06-14-2019'},
    'jul19' : {'06-15-2019' : '07-14-2019'},
    'aug19' : {'07-15-2019' : '08-14-2019'},
    'sep19' : {'08-15-2019' : '09-14-2019'},
    'oct19' : {'09-15-2019' : '10-14-2019'},
    'nov19' : {'10-15-2019' : '11-14-2019'}
}
```

How could I get these summed values into a pandas dataframe where the row name would == the nested dictionary name of the summed data? I am not sure if using a nested dictionary is the right path. Any tips greatly appreciated for a better method to the madness.

```
def myprint(d):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            myprint(v)
        else:
            print("{0} : {1}".format(k, v))
```

***EDIT***
On my real world example I can sum a date range with this below, but I was hoping to create some sort of a loop/automated process...
`weath.loc['11-15-2017' : '12-14-2017'].sum()`

Comment: Note that you have duplicate keys in the dictionary, which will replace the existing ones

Comment: whoops that wont work

Comment: Also please add the expected output

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: I'd suggest you to simplify the example, and add the expected output. Seems quite unclear for now

Comment: can you see the EDIT?

Comment: What kind of output do you expect?

Comment: Because this has to be done for each dict entry right?

Comment: The out put I was hoping for is a pandas dictionary with summed values between the date ranges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple structure for storing date ranges and then,

```
>>> dates = {'dec17': ('11-15-2017', '12-14-2017'), 'jan18': ('12-15-2017', '01-14-2018')}
>>> odf = pd.DataFrame()
>>> for name, date_range in dates.items():
...     start, end = date_range
...     print(df.loc[start:end].sum().to_frame().T)
...
```